# Skia Canvas : ERR_DLOPEN_FAILED

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, svg, serverless, skia

So im using  [canvas-constructor](https://www.npmjs.com/package/canvas-constructor) (dependent on [Skia canvas](https://www.npmjs.com/package/skia-canvas)) to do some image processing (instead of [node-canvas](https://www.npmjs.com/package/canvas) due to incompatibility issues with [sharp library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sharp))

**Update : getting the same error while using canvas as well**

**Whenever i run my code locally, it runs flawlessly.**

**When i deploy it to AWS and run my lambda, I get the following error :**

[image: Cloudwatch log for my lamda]

My **Lambda** code ( Running Nodejs14.x **Not Working**) :

```
         let SERIALIZED = frameDom.serialize() //returns a string

         SERIALIZED = SERIALIZED.replace('<html>','')
         SERIALIZED = SERIALIZED.replace('</html>','')
         SERIALIZED = SERIALIZED.replace('<head>','')
         SERIALIZED = SERIALIZED.replace('</head>','')
         SERIALIZED = SERIALIZED.replace('<body>','')
         SERIALIZED = SERIALIZED.replace('</body>','')

         sharp(Buffer.from(SERIALIZED,'utf-8')).toFormat("png").toBuffer(async (err, data, info) => {
                          
               //data is output file buffer

               const image = await resolveImage(data);
               let _canvas = new Canvas(97, 96).printImage(image, 0, 0, 97, 96)

               const FINAL = convertImage(_canvas.canvas.getContext("2d").getImageData(0, 0, 97, 96))
          })
```

My Code **Locally** (Windows 10 env **Working**) :

**Note** : *test.svg was downloaded from my s3 bucket where* **frameDom.serialize()** *(in my lambda code) was the image body when it was stored*

```
fs.readFile('./test.svg', 'utf8' , (err, image) => {

    if (err)
        throw new Error("Error openning frame")

    image = image.replace('<html>','')
    image = image.replace('</html>','')
    image = image.replace('<head>','')
    image = image.replace('</head>','')
    image = image.replace('<body>','')
    image = image.replace('</body>','')



    sharp(Buffer.from(image,'utf-8')).toFormat("png").toBuffer(async (err, data, info) => {
                              
        //data is output file buffer

    const image = await resolveImage(data);

    let canvas = new Canvas(97, 96).printImage(image, 0, 0, 97, 96)

    

    fs.writeFile('./new.svg', Ass.convertImage(canvas.canvas.getContext("2d").getImageData(0, 0, 97, 96)), err => {
        if (err) {
          console.error(err)
          return
        }
    })

  })
})
```

Comment: Probably useful: https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas/issues/1000

Comment: I tried downloading the dependencies on ec2 and manually adding them then deploying. no luck... size was too large

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like the modules need to be installed using an amazon linux OS. They still come out to be large. My only solution was to dockerize my lambda code , host it on ECR, then have my serverless application point to the image to use when a request is made to it